# Problems with selenium python and cookies

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I have encountered an issue while using the driver.add_cookie(cookie) method in the following code snippet:

```
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Restoring authentication data on another computer

with open('auth_data.json', 'r') as file:
  auth_data = json.load(file)

# Restoring authentication cookies

for cookie in auth_data['cookies']:
  driver.add_cookie(cookie)

time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

My program downloads data and cookies from the server to restore the session for the Chrome driver. Sometimes, on the end user's computer, the session gets invalidated with the following error:
`ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(102)\] Failed to decrypt: Key not valid for use in specified state. (0x8009000B)`

It seems like the cookies may not be fully loaded or there could be an issue with my method. If you know any methods to load cookies before navigating to a website in Selenium Python, I would greatly appreciate your help!

I tried updating and setting different expectations, I do not know which way to go yet

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```
# open then website
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Opening JSON file
f = open('auth_data.json')
cookies = json.load(f)
# load cookies to the driver
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

time.sleep(2)
# refresh the browser
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(2)
```